# Looking for online PDF annotation tool with the ability to sync with iPad and highlight extraction

Tags: pdf, pdf-viewer, annotation

I'm actively looking for a software which lets me read, highlight/annotate PDF files online (web-based) and also do the same on iPad using a software. Additionally, a Windows application which lets me extract the highlights from the PDF file.

I've tried Mendeley, unfortunately the drawback is it's not possible to extract the highlights, and other PDF readers, like Acrobat, Phantom, etc. do not recognise the highlights. Obviously because Mendeley uses a different standard. With Adobe products, it's impossible to highlight online.

Comment: Is there a reason why it has to be online (assuming that you would do that on a Windows/Mac machine? Actually, using Acrobat/Reader as driver for the PDF display in the browser should give you the commenting tools (but there are not many browsers left which support the Acrobat Browser plug-in).

Comment: I need the web version to use at work, hence it's against the policies to install an application but allowed to use the web version.
An iOS version to use on my iPad; and hopefully a windows version to use on another desktop (which is not that important)